# Accessing table data in different forms Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataformat

I have T table as follows.

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
FirstName = {'Amanda' ;'Brenda';'Carl'; 'Denis'; 'Ethan'};
Something = {'String1' ;'String2';'String2'; 'String1'; 'String5'};
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
FavoriteColor = {'blue' ;'red' ;'yellow'; 'orange' ;'colorblind' };
T = table(Age,FirstName,Weight,FavoriteColor,Something,'RowNames',LastName)
T.FavoriteColor= categorical(T.FavoriteColor);
T.Something= categorical(T.Something);
```

when I use

```
A=T(:,5);
```

I get a variable A which is a table as well. But when I use

```
A=T.Something;
```

I get a variable A which is a categorical value like the ones is column Something. I want to use loops so I need to use the first one with indices but I want the result in the second one. What should I do?

Comment: Differing indexing syntax will result in different output types. Read [the documentation for tables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html), specifically [Accessing Data in a Table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `a=T{:,5};`  solved the problem.